# What is the best way to make an image appear in a specific div in response to a button click event?

Tags: javascript, html

It is pretty simple.  I just want to have a clickable word/button that will activate an image to appear into a div.  What is the cleanest way to do this? thanks

Comment: using javascript is the best way

Comment: i n javascipt add even listener for button and call a function that will add img element inside div.

Answer (score 1):

Quickest way would be to add a blank image tag where you want the image to appear, and then use jquery to add/change the source

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    $('#imgonclick').attr('src', 'http://example.com/myimage.jpg');
});
```

whhere #button is a button with class button, and #imgonclick is an img tag with class of imgonclick

Answer (score 0):

Jquery is super easy, but if you have to stick to JavaScript you can try something like this:

```
<div id="image"></div>
<button id="imgBtn" type="button" onclick="displayBtn()">Click Me</button>
```

```
function displayBtn() {
   document.getElementById("image").src = "something.gif";
}
```

OR... if the div already has an image src property set, just show it.

```
<div id="image" src="something.gif" style="display: none;"></div>
<button id="imgBtn" type="button" onclick="displayBtn()">Click Me</button>
```

```
function displayBtn() {
   document.getElementById("image").style.display = "block";
}
```